# Xcode4 : custom task for copying resources to the bundle

Tags: xcode, resources, task

Folks, is it possible to create a custom task for copying resources in Xcode?

I'd like to use rsync instead of Xcode's built-in resource copy tasks. From time to time Xcode for some reason doesn't copy modified resources to the bundle so I'd like to have a better control over this task.

I think I need some magic variable which points to the destination bundle directory, so I could create the following task:

rsync -a ${SRCROOT}/resources ${PATH_TO_THE_BUNDLE}/

...but I have no idea if there is such a variable.

**Update:** I tried ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} variable and it points to some intermediate directory while during the runtime **[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: my_path ofType: nil]** returns something completely different. Is there any Xcode variable which which returns the same result as NSBundle does?

Answer (score 2):

Yes... it sounds like you already know how to add a "Run Script" action to a build scheme, and the magic variables you may want are either:

`$SRCROOT` -- the source tree's root directory

`$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` -- the convoluted path to the destination where the built product eventually arrives at (i.e. and yes, this variable's contents changes slightly depending on whether you are building a Mac app, or an iPhone app targeting the simulator or the device)

So... it sounds like what you want is `"$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/Contents/Resources"` in your build script?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I need... In my case $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR points to one place while during the runtime [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: path ofType: nil] returns something completely different. Is there any Xcode variable which which returns the same result as NSBundle does?

Answer (score 0):

To do this on a **per-directory** basis:

1. Add a 'Run Script Build Phase' (Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Build Phase)
2. Copy/paste the following script into the build phase (don't forget to set the actual paths on line 1):

---

```
dirsToCopy=("path1/directory1","path2/directory2")

for INPATTERN in "${dirsToCopy[@]}"; do
    INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$INPATTERN/*
    OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/$INPATTERN
    cp -R $INDIR $OUTDIR
done
```

---

For those not used to working with shell scripts:

- paths on line 1 of the script are relative to the project directory (where the .xcodeproj file resides)
- you can add more (or less) paths to the array `dirsToCopy` if you want
- you can change the pattern of files to copy where variable `INDIR` is defined
- you can change how the copying is done (currently, recursive due to `-R`) by changing the flags to `cp` in the last line of script within the for block.